# ContextualVersionConflict when importing guesslang package

Tags: python, import, python-import, conflicting-libraries

When importing `guesslang` package, I've got `ContextualVersionConflict` error about `html5lib` package.

```
ContextualVersionConflict: (html5lib 1.0.1 (/Users/user_name/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('html5lib==0.9999999'), {'tensorboard'})
```

I reinstalled `html5lib` once with version `1.0.1` and did again with version `0.9999999` (seven 9s), but the result is same in both tries.

This is the code I ran.

```
from guesslang import Guess
code_snippet = "import numpy as np"
print(Guess().language_name(code_snippet))
```

Whole error message.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ContextualVersionConflict                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-113-766936e416d4> in <module>
----> 1 from guesslang import Guess
      2 code_snippet = "import numpy as np"
      3 print(Guess().language_name(code_snippet))

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/guesslang/__init__.py in <module>
      6 
      7 from guesslang.config import config_logging  # noqa: F401
----> 8 from guesslang.guesser import Guess  # noqa: F401
      9 from guesslang.utils import GuesslangError  # noqa: F401
     10 

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/guesslang/guesser.py in <module>
     11 
     12 from guesslang.config import model_info, config_dict
---> 13 from guesslang.extractor import extract, CONTENT_SIZE
     14 from guesslang.utils import (
     15     search_files, extract_from_files, safe_read_file, GuesslangError, DataSet)

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/guesslang/extractor.py in <module>
     14 
     15 SPECIAL_KEYWORDS = {'num': '<number>', 'var': '<variable>'}
---> 16 KEYWORDS = config_dict('keywords.json')
     17 
     18 SEPARATOR = re.compile(r'(\W)')

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/guesslang/config.py in config_dict(name)
     73 def config_dict(name: str) -> Dict[str, Any]:
     74     """Load a JSON configuration dict from Guesslang config directory.
---> 75 
     76     :param name: the JSON file name.
     77     :return: configuration

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resource_string(self, package_or_requirement, resource_name)
   1154     def resource_string(self, package_or_requirement, resource_name):
   1155         """Return specified resource as a string"""
-> 1156         return get_provider(package_or_requirement).get_resource_string(
   1157             self, resource_name
   1158         )

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in get_provider(moduleOrReq)
    355     """Return an IResourceProvider for the named module or requirement"""
    356     if isinstance(moduleOrReq, Requirement):
--> 357         return working_set.find(moduleOrReq) or require(str(moduleOrReq))[0]
    358     try:
    359         module = sys.modules[moduleOrReq]

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in require(self, *requirements)
    898         included, even if they were already activated in this working set.
    899         """
--> 900         needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
    901 
    902         for dist in needed:

~/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, extras)
    789                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
    790                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 791                 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
    792 
    793             # push the new requirements onto the stack

ContextualVersionConflict: (html5lib 1.0.1 (/Users/hidenori/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-5.1.0/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('html5lib==0.9999999'), {'tensorboard'})
```

The result of `pip list`.

```
Package                                 Version      
--------------------------------------- -------------
absl-py                                 0.9.0        
alabaster                               0.7.12       
algorithmia                             1.2.1        
algorithmia-api-client                  1.1.0        
anaconda-client                         1.7.2        
anaconda-navigator                      1.9.7        
anaconda-project                        0.8.2        
applaunchservices                       0.2.1        
appnope                                 0.1.0        
appscript                               1.0.1        
argh                                    0.26.2       
asn1crypto                              0.24.0       
astor                                   0.8.1        
astroid                                 2.2.5        
astropy                                 3.1.2        
atomicwrites                            1.3.0        
attrs                                   19.1.0       
autopep8                                1.4.4        
Babel                                   2.6.0        
backcall                                0.1.0        
backports.os                            0.1.1        
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size      1.0.0        
beautifulsoup4                          4.7.1        
bitarray                                0.9.0        
bkcharts                                0.2          
blaze                                   0.11.3       
bleach                                  1.5.0        
bokeh                                   1.1.0        
boto                                    2.49.0       
boto3                                   1.9.199      
botocore                                1.12.199     
Bottleneck                              1.2.1        
certifi                                 2019.3.9     
cffi                                    1.12.3       
chardet                                 3.0.4        
chromedriver-binary                     74.0.3729.6.0
Click                                   7.0          
cloudpickle                             0.8.1        
clyent                                  1.2.2        
colorama                                0.4.1        
conda                                   4.6.14       
conda-build                             3.17.8       
conda-verify                            3.1.1        
contextlib2                             0.5.5        
coverage                                5.0.1        
cryptography                            2.6.1        
cycler                                  0.10.0       
Cython                                  0.29.7       
cytoolz                                 0.9.0.1      
dask                                    1.2.0        
datashape                               0.5.4        
decorator                               4.4.0        
defusedxml                              0.6.0        
diff-match-patch                        20181111     
distributed                             1.27.1       
docutils                                0.14         
dominate                                2.3.1        
dryscrape                               1.0          
entrypoints                             0.3          
enum34                                  1.1.6        
et-xmlfile                              1.0.1        
fastcache                               1.0.2        
filelock                                3.0.10       
flake8                                  3.7.9        
Flask                                   1.0.2        
Flask-Bootstrap                         3.3.7.1      
Flask-Cors                              3.0.7        
future                                  0.17.1       
gast                                    0.3.2        
gensim                                  3.8.0        
gevent                                  1.4.0        
gitdb2                                  2.0.5        
GitPython                               3.0.2        
glob2                                   0.6          
gmpy2                                   2.0.8        
greenlet                                0.4.15       
grpcio                                  1.26.0       
guesslang                               0.9.4        
h5py                                    2.8.0        
heapdict                                1.0.0        
helpdev                                 0.6.10       
html5lib                                0.9999999    
idna                                    2.8          
imageio                                 2.5.0        
imagesize                               1.1.0        
importlib-metadata                      1.3.0        
imutils                                 0.5.2        
intervaltree                            3.0.2        
ipykernel                               5.1.0        
ipython                                 7.5.0        
ipython-genutils                        0.2.0        
ipywidgets                              7.4.2        
iso8601                                 0.1.12       
isort                                   4.3.17       
itsdangerous                            1.1.0        
jdcal                                   1.4.1        
jedi                                    0.14.1       
Jinja2                                  2.10.1       
jmespath                                0.9.4        
jsonschema                              3.0.1        
jupyter                                 1.0.0        
jupyter-client                          5.2.4        
jupyter-console                         6.0.0        
jupyter-core                            4.4.0        
jupyterlab                              0.35.5       
jupyterlab-launcher                     0.13.1       
jupyterlab-server                       0.2.0        
jupyterthemes                           0.20.0       
keyring                                 18.0.0       
kiwisolver                              1.1.0        
langdetect                              1.0.7        
lazy-object-proxy                       1.3.1        
lesscpy                                 0.13.0       
libarchive-c                            2.8          
lief                                    0.9.0        
ll                                      1.0          
llvmlite                                0.28.0       
locket                                  0.2.0        
lxml                                    4.3.3        
Markdown                                3.1.1        
MarkupSafe                              1.1.1        
matplotlib                              3.0.3        
mccabe                                  0.6.1        
mecab-python3                           0.996.2      
mistune                                 0.8.4        
mock                                    3.0.5        
more-itertools                          8.0.2        
mpmath                                  1.1.0        
msgpack                                 0.6.1        
multipledispatch                        0.6.0        
navigator-updater                       0.2.1        
nbconvert                               5.5.0        
nbformat                                4.4.0        
networkx                                2.3          
nltk                                    3.4.1        
nose                                    1.3.7        
notebook                                5.7.8        
numba                                   0.43.1       
numexpr                                 2.6.9        
numpy                                   1.16.3       
numpydoc                                0.9.1        
odo                                     0.5.1        
olefile                                 0.46         
openpyxl                                2.6.2        
packaging                               19.0         
pandas                                  0.24.2       
pandocfilters                           1.4.2        
parso                                   0.5.2        
partd                                   0.3.10       
path.py                                 12.0.1       
pathlib2                                2.3.3        
pathtools                               0.1.2        
patsy                                   0.5.1        
pdf2image                               1.5.1        
PeakUtils                               1.1.1        
pep8                                    1.7.1        
pexpect                                 4.7.0        
pickleshare                             0.7.5        
Pillow                                  6.0.0        
pip                                     19.1         
pip-conflict-checker                    0.6.0        
pkginfo                                 1.5.0.1      
pluggy                                  0.9.0        
ply                                     3.11         
prometheus-client                       0.6.0        
prompt-toolkit                          2.0.9        
protobuf                                3.11.2       
psutil                                  5.6.2        
ptyprocess                              0.6.0        
py                                      1.8.0        
pycodestyle                             2.5.0        
pycosat                                 0.6.3        
pycparser                               2.19         
pycrypto                                2.6.1        
pycurl                                  7.43.0.2     
pydocstyle                              5.0.1        
pydot                                   1.2.4        
pyflakes                                2.1.1        
Pygments                                2.3.1        
pylint                                  2.3.1        
pymongo                                 3.9.0        
Pympler                                 0.8          
pyobjc                                  6.1          
pyobjc-core                             6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Accounts               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-AdSupport              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit         6.1          
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC        6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ApplicationServices    6.1          
pyobjc-framework-AuthenticationServices 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Automator              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-AVFoundation           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-AVKit                  6.1          
pyobjc-framework-BusinessChat           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CalendarStore          6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CloudKit               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa                  6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration          6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ColorSync              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Contacts               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ContactsUI             6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudio              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreAudioKit           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreBluetooth          6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreData               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreHaptics            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreMedia              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreMediaIO            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreML                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreMotion             6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreServices           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreSpotlight          6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreText               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CoreWLAN               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-CryptoTokenKit         6.1          
pyobjc-framework-DeviceCheck            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices     6.1          
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecording          6.1          
pyobjc-framework-DiscRecordingUI        6.1          
pyobjc-framework-DiskArbitration        6.1          
pyobjc-framework-DVDPlayback            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-EventKit               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling      6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ExecutionPolicy        6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ExternalAccessory      6.1          
pyobjc-framework-FileProvider           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-FileProviderUI         6.1          
pyobjc-framework-FinderSync             6.1          
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-GameCenter             6.1          
pyobjc-framework-GameController         6.1          
pyobjc-framework-GameKit                6.1          
pyobjc-framework-GameplayKit            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ImageCaptureCore       6.1          
pyobjc-framework-IMServicePlugIn        6.1          
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit         6.1          
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins       6.1          
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage         6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Intents                6.1          
pyobjc-framework-IOSurface              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-iTunesLibrary          6.1          
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping  6.1          
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices         6.1          
pyobjc-framework-libdispatch            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-LinkPresentation       6.1          
pyobjc-framework-LocalAuthentication    6.1          
pyobjc-framework-MapKit                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-MediaAccessibility     6.1          
pyobjc-framework-MediaLibrary           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-MediaPlayer            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-MediaToolbox           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-MetalKit               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ModelIO                6.1          
pyobjc-framework-MultipeerConnectivity  6.1          
pyobjc-framework-NaturalLanguage        6.1          
pyobjc-framework-NetFS                  6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Network                6.1          
pyobjc-framework-NetworkExtension       6.1          
pyobjc-framework-NotificationCenter     6.1          
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory          6.1          
pyobjc-framework-OSAKit                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-OSLog                  6.1          
pyobjc-framework-PencilKit              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Photos                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-PhotosUI               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes        6.1          
pyobjc-framework-PubSub                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-PushKit                6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Quartz                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-QuickLookThumbnailing  6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SafariServices         6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SceneKit               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver            6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge        6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Security               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SecurityFoundation     6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SecurityInterface      6.1          
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement      6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Social                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SoundAnalysis          6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Speech                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SpriteKit              6.1          
pyobjc-framework-StoreKit               6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration    6.1          
pyobjc-framework-SystemExtensions       6.1          
pyobjc-framework-UserNotifications      6.1          
pyobjc-framework-VideoSubscriberAccount 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-VideoToolbox           6.1          
pyobjc-framework-Vision                 6.1          
pyobjc-framework-WebKit                 6.1          
pyodbc                                  4.0.26       
pyOpenSSL                               19.0.0       
pyparsing                               2.4.0        
PyQt5                                   5.12.3       
PyQt5-sip                               12.7.0       
PyQtWebEngine                           5.12.1       
pyrsistent                              0.14.11      
pyserial                                3.4          
PySocks                                 1.6.8        
pytest                                  4.4.1        
pytest-arraydiff                        0.3          
pytest-astropy                          0.5.0        
pytest-doctestplus                      0.3.0        
pytest-openfiles                        0.3.2        
pytest-remotedata                       0.3.1        
python-dateutil                         2.8.0        
python-jsonrpc-server                   0.3.2        
python-language-server                  0.31.2       
pytz                                    2019.1       
PyWavelets                              1.0.3        
PyYAML                                  5.1          
pyzmq                                   18.0.0       
QDarkStyle                              2.7          
QtAwesome                               0.5.7        
qtconsole                               4.6.0        
QtPy                                    1.7.0        
requests                                2.21.0       
rope                                    0.14.0       
ruamel-yaml                             0.15.46      
s3transfer                              0.2.1        
scikit-image                            0.15.0       
scikit-learn                            0.20.3       
scipy                                   1.2.1        
seaborn                                 0.9.0        
selenium                                3.141.0      
Send2Trash                              1.5.0        
setuptools                              41.0.1       
simplegeneric                           0.8.1        
singledispatch                          3.4.0.3      
six                                     1.13.0       
smart-open                              1.8.4        
smmap2                                  2.0.5        
snowballstemmer                         1.2.1        
sortedcollections                       1.1.2        
sortedcontainers                        2.1.0        
soupsieve                               1.8          
Sphinx                                  2.0.1        
sphinxcontrib-applehelp                 1.0.1        
sphinxcontrib-devhelp                   1.0.1        
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp                  1.0.2        
sphinxcontrib-jsmath                    1.0.1        
sphinxcontrib-qthelp                    1.0.2        
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml           1.1.3        
sphinxcontrib-websupport                1.1.0        
spyder                                  4.0.0        
spyder-kernels                          1.8.1        
SQLAlchemy                              1.3.3        
statsmodels                             0.9.0        
sympy                                   1.4          
tables                                  3.4.4        
tabulate                                0.8.6        
tblib                                   1.3.2        
tensorboard                             1.6.0        
tensorflow                              1.7.0rc1     
tensorflow-tensorboard                  1.5.1        
termcolor                               1.1.0        
terminado                               0.8.2        
testpath                                0.4.2        
toolz                                   0.9.0        
tornado                                 6.0.2        
tqdm                                    4.31.1       
traitlets                               4.3.2        
typed-ast                               1.3.4        
typing                                  3.6.4        
ujson                                   1.35         
unicodecsv                              0.14.1       
urllib3                                 1.24.2       
visitor                                 0.1.3        
watchdog                                0.9.0        
wcwidth                                 0.1.7        
webencodings                            0.5.1        
webkit-server                           1.0          
Werkzeug                                0.15.2       
wheel                                   0.33.1       
widgetsnbextension                      3.4.2        
wrapt                                   1.11.1       
wurlitzer                               2.0.0        
xlrd                                    1.2.0        
XlsxWriter                              1.1.7        
xlwings                                 0.15.6       
xlwt                                    1.2.0        
xvfbwrapper                             0.2.9        
yapf                                    0.29.0       
zict                                    0.1.4        
zipp                                    0.6.0
```

Comment: I am facing same problem. Did you get any solution?

Comment: I am sorry, but I have just avoided to use this package.